# For index in list

Tags: python, for-loop, indexof

I'm struggling with finding out how to simplify answers from a subtraction to 2 decimal places. The two lists Enter and Leave are subtracted so I can get the time it takes for a car to get from point A to B.

```
Enter=[7.12,
       7.15,
       7.24,
       7.45,
       7.28,
       7.31,
       7.18,
       7.25,
       7.33,
       7.38]

Leave=[7.56,
       7.24,
       7.48,
       7.52,
       7.45,
       7.57,
       7.22,
       7.31,
       7.37,
       7.41]

Timestaken=[]

for enter_data, leave_data in zip(Enter, Leave):
    Timestaken.append(leave_data-enter_data)

print (Timestaken)

for index in Timestaken:
    Timestaken[index]="%.2f" % Timestaken[index]

print(Timestaken)
```

When I run it in IDLE, I receive the following:

```
>>> 
[0.4399999999999995, 0.08999999999999986, 0.2400000000000002, 0.0699999999999994, 0.16999999999999993, 0.2600000000000007, 0.040000000000000036, 0.05999999999999961, 0.040000000000000036, 0.03000000000000025]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\Task 2 Testing.py", line 46, in <module>
    Timestaken[index]="%.2f" % Timestaken[index]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
```

I need help with this bit:

```
for index in Timestaken:
    Timestaken[index]="%.2f" % Timestaken[index]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
for value in Timestaken:
    print("%.2f" % value)
```

Answer (score 1):

## You have a wrong assumption on  `index` value

```
for index in Timestaken:
```

this code will iterate over all of the **values** of the `Timestaken` list, not its indices :

```
In [9]: [index for index in Timestaken]
Out[9]:
[0.4399999999999995,
 0.08999999999999986,
 0.2400000000000002,
 0.0699999999999994,
 0.16999999999999993,
 0.2600000000000007,
 0.040000000000000036,
 0.05999999999999961,
 0.040000000000000036,
 0.03000000000000025]
```

If you really want to have indices as well as values, use `enumerate`:

```
In [10]: [(index,value) for index,value in enumerate(Timestaken)]
Out[10]:
[(0, 0.4399999999999995),
 (1, 0.08999999999999986),
 (2, 0.2400000000000002),
 (3, 0.0699999999999994),
 (4, 0.16999999999999993),
 (5, 0.2600000000000007),
 (6, 0.040000000000000036),
 (7, 0.05999999999999961),
 (8, 0.040000000000000036),
 (9, 0.03000000000000025)]
```

---

### With your code : No need for those `appends`and reformatting

```
times_taken = [leave_data-enter_data for enter_data, leave_data in zip(Enter, Leave)]


print (times_taken)

times_taken_float = ["{%.2f}".format(value) for value in times_taken]

print (times_taken_float)
```

I used list comprehension to simplify the operations

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
for index in Timestaken:
    Timestaken[index]="%.2f" % Timestaken[index]
```

you are using values in the list Timestaken not indices to those values

you'll want something like the following

```
for index in xrange(len(Timestaken)):
    Timestaken[index]="%.2f" % Timestaken[index]
```

This method works for python 2.x, if you're using python 3.x use `range` instead of `xrange`

where `xrange(len(Timestaken))` returns a generator that yields 0, 1, ... len(Timestaken)-1

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\Task 2 Testing.py", line 45, in <module>
    for index in xrange(len(Timestaken)):
NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined`

Comment: I guess, I should have asked what version of python you are running. I believe `xrange` is valid in 2.x and in 3.x it is just `range`.

Comment: Ah, sorry. My bad for not including the python version. Thanks too!

Answer (score 1):

More pythonic:

```
>>> enter = [7.12, 7.15, 7.24, 7.45, 7.28, 7.31, 7.18, 7.25, 7.33, 7.38]
>>> leave = [7.56, 7.24, 7.48, 7.52, 7.45, 7.57, 7.22, 7.31, 7.37, 7.41]

>>> timestaken=["%.2f" % (leave_data-enter_data) for enter_data, leave_data in zip(enter, leave)]
>>> print (timestaken)
['0.44', '0.09', '0.24', '0.07', '0.17', '0.26', '0.04', '0.06', '0.04', '0.03']
>>>
```